# Snowflake snowalert - running selective alerts

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to run only specific snowalert alerts

I am setting up snowalerts and as part of that I am running the snowalerts with the following command:

```
docker run --env-file file.envs snowsec/snowalert ./run all
 or 
docker run --env-file file.envs snowsec/snowalert ./run alerts
```

Is there a way to run only specific alerts?

What I want to ask is that currently on either commands ALL alerts get run.

I would like to run specific alerts so that I can schedule them separately.

Looking forward to any advice around that

Comment: Not sure if there is a switch for specific alerts to be run but some of the alerts can be suppressed using the steps listed here : https://snowalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/manage.html#adding-suppressions

Comment: Thanks @SrinathMenon for the suggestion! Do you have any example of how to create a snowalert supression?

There are quite a few examples of creating alert queries but none for creating suppressions